# An image of a sphere under continuous mapping.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $\varphi:R^n\to R^n$ and $\varphi$ is continuous on the sphere  $S=S(x,r)$.
It is somehow clear that the image $\varphi(S)$  is a connected compact.
My interest is what can we say about $R^n\setminus\varphi(S)$ ?

I'm thinking in following way: if $\varphi$ is injective then $R^n\setminus\varphi(S)$ consist of two components bounded and unbounded. It is Jordan theorem in $R^n$. But I haven't found correct references for this assertion.

Comment: Here it is an answer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called the Jordan-Brouwer separation theorem. There is a sketch of proof [in the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem#Proof_and_generalizations); the proof uses homology theoretical methods. A possible reference is [this paper](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Schmaltz.pdf) by Wolfgang Schmaltz (the proof is very much too complicated to be included here...).